# WA site scores in dbRDA

Tags: vegan

I am working on a project trying to investigate differences in Bray-Curtis Dissimilarity (BCD) between 2 areas. There are 5 replicate samples in each area and 5 years of data. I also have a suite of habitat data. I am looking to use `vegan::dbrda()` to accomplish this.

My idea is to run `dbrda(BCD~area*as.factor(year))`; the resulting constrained axis scores from this analysis should give me the variation in my BCD attributable to differences between areas, and between areas over time. I could then use those constrained axis scores as response variables in down-stream `rda()` analysis such as looking at which taxa and habitat variables are associated with differences between areas.

I am fairly new to distance based statistics, but have some experience with CCA and RDA. My question is, how are WA scores actually calculated in dbrda (considering there are no taxa to weigh the site scores)? And would WA scores be useful in this fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no WA scores in objects returned by `dbrda()`, in fact there are no species scores returned *at all*. This is largely for the reason you mention; if all we have at the point of fitting the dbRDA are the dissimilarities between samples in the species space then we don't have any species information from which to calculate scores.

*vegan* does have the `sppscores()` function to add species scores to the `dbrda()` object however. I would recommend that you read the help for `?sppscores` as it explains some of the issues.

Importantly, the scores that are added are linear combination scores (i.e. they are a linear combination of the sample scores on respective axes, weighted by abudance), so the species scores (coordinates) are the heads of vectors (arrows) that emanate from the origin of the ordination plot (0,0), and point in the direction of linearly-increasing abundance.

Comment: But there are WA scores if I run: `data("varespec"); data("varechem"); BCD<-vegan::vegdist(as.matrix(varespec)); tst1<-vegan::dbrda(BCD~.,data=varechem); tst1$CCA$wa;` What do those represent?

Comment: There aren't WA scores in any linear method. The presence of `$CCA$wa` *in an **RDA** * is an unfortunate legacy of the origins of the *vegan* package. RDA and CCA are internally almost exactly equivalent; the CCA version being weight by row and column sums and then subject to a post-analysis transformation. Jari kept the same internal object structure when he wrote `rda()`, which was some time after he wrote `cca()`. 1/2

Comment: This is also a good lesson in not delving into objects returned by R functions unless you understand how they were computed and therefore what they represent. `$CCA$wa` doesn't even refer to the species; in (C)CA these would be the raw (unscaled) weighted average *site* scores. I suspect that these are linear combination *site* scores in the `dbrda()`; they are certainly a function of the eigenvectors. If you do `tst1$CCA$wa` and `scores(tst1, display = 'sites')` you'll see these are site scores, demonstrating that you should use `scores()` to access things you want from ordination objects.

Comment: Re my last comment, the two components will differ (the `scores()` function is doing some scaling to the raw scores). What I meant to say was you'll notice that the rownames on the scores match and therefore they are about the **sites** (samples).

Comment: Thanks Gavi, but am still confused about the implementation of `dbrda()`. If you run: `data("varespec"); data("varechem"); BCD<-vegan::vegdist(as.matrix(varespec));dt<-data.frame(fact1=rep(c("a","b"),length.out=12),fact2=rep(c("z","y","x","w"),each=6)); tst1<-vegan::dbrda(BCD~fact1*fact2,data=dt)` and when you plot the result: `ordiplot(tst1); ordiplot(tst1,display="lc"); ordiplot(tst1,display="wa")` I'm confused about what is actually being plotted in these two cases if there are no WA scores, and why is `scores(tst1, display = 'sites')` more similar to WA scores?

Comment: *** Gavin, my apologies for mistyping your name

Comment: If you did an actual RDA, the `$wa` would contain the site scores and `$lc` would contain the linear constraint site scores. The latter are site scores that are closest to the regression face of the constrained ordination. The `$wa` site scores are a step removed from the regression & reflect relationships with the species. In `dbrda()` we don't have species but we still have variables (from the dissimilarities) that get ordinated. Those scores in a dbRDA object reflect the same transformations implied by RDA but are no longer done on species but the variables created from the dissimilairties.

Comment: The naming of these components is an unfortunate side-effect of the legacy of development; CCA was implemented first, other methods much later and the underlying organisation of the objects for CCA was reused. In an ideal world we'd change this, but too many people are doing like you have and are working with the internal representation and not using the correct extractor functions.

Comment: `$wa` contains *raw* or *unscaled* scores. `scores()` returns scaled scores; exactly what and how is scaled depending on the values of arguments `scaling` and `correlation` (for linear methods; for unimodal methods we have argument `hill` instead). Very rarely do you want the raw or unscaled scores. `scores()` uses a default. which can be changed. `scores(tst1, display = 'sites', scaling = 'none')` will get you what is in `tst1$CCA$wa` (well, the first two columns of by default). But none of these are *species* scores as the function doesn't ever know about the species info.

Comment: Okay, now that makes sense. Thank you Gavin!